# Can someone explain what the Brant test in R does?

Tags: regression, logistic, assumptions, ordered-logit, polr

I’m using R to run proportional odds models through the `polr` function in the `MASS` package. I want to see if the proportional odds or parallel lines assumption holds and I have come across the `brant` package. Can someone explain/break down what the brant test from the `brant` package actually does?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The previous answer described Brant's test as he proposed it.  The test that's implemented in the `brant` package turns out to be different; it looks for all possible differences between $\beta$s at different cutpoints, not at the particular alternative Brant suggested.  This all-possible-departures test is described in the original paper by Brant, but he argues that it wouldn't be very helpful

**Previous answer**

More seriously, if your outcome variable $Y$ is ordinal, you can dichotomise it at $k$ and get a set of $k-1$ logistic models

$$\mathrm{logit} P[Y>k] = x\beta_k-\alpha_k$$

It is not possible for the $\alpha_k$ to be the same for different $k$, but it is possible for the $\beta_k$ to be the same. The proportional odds model comes from the assumption that they are the same.

Since the $\beta_k$ are the same under the proportional odds model, any $\hat\beta_k -\hat\beta_j$ is a reasonable test statistic for the proportional odds assumption.  [The Brant test](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2532457) computes the variance-covariance matrix of all the $\hat\beta_k$, so that any departure from proportional odds could in principle be examined.  However, as Brant noted, a test that tries to detect everything will have poor power for any specific alternative. For this reason, the test focuses on the alternative $\beta_k=\phi_k\beta$, which will tend to arise either if the true link function is not the logit or if there is misclassification in $Y$.

So, the Brant test is a test of $\beta_k=\beta$ vs $\beta_k=\phi_k\beta$, and it is a Wald-type test, based on differences in $\hat\beta_k$ and their estimated variances.

Comment: So does βk=β mean that all βk are the same (proportional odds) and βk=ϕkβ means that the proportional odds assumption has failed? 

Could you also please explain what ϕkβ is?

Comment: Yes $\beta_k=\beta$ implies they are the same and $\beta_k=\phi_k\beta$ is one way they could be different.  It says that the coefficients for different variables change the same way with $k$